# startActivityForResult Crashes in fragment

Tags: android, camera, startactivityforresult

error occurs when `startActvityResult()` called.

I use this to call FragmentFotosdePerfil from other fragment

```
public void verFotosPerfil(String userID){

    fragmentFotosPerfil=new FragmentFotosPerfil();
    Bundle bundle= new Bundle();
    bundle.putString("userID",userID);
    fragmentFotosPerfil.setArguments(bundle);
    getFragmentManager().beginTransaction().
    replace(R.id.frameLayout2,fragmentFotosPerfil).commit();

}
```

I call "cargarFotoPerfil" from the XML with Onclick in different buttons

```
 public void cargarFotoPerfil(View view){


    switch(view.getId()) {
        case R.id.btnCargarFoto2:
            System.out.println("caso2");
          cargarFotoPerfil2(view);
            foto=2;
            break;
        case R.id.btnCargarFoto3:
            cargarFotoPerfil2(view);
            foto=3;
            break;
        case R.id.btnCargarFoto4:
            cargarFotoPerfil2(view);
            foto=4;
            break;

        case R.id.btnCargarFoto5:
            cargarFotoPerfil2(view);
            foto=5;
            break;

    }

    public void cargarFotoPerfil2(View view){

        final CharSequence[] opciones={"Elegir de Galeria","Cancelar"};
        final AlertDialog.Builder builder=new 
        AlertDialog.Builder(view.getContext());
        builder.setTitle("Elige una Opción");
        builder.setItems(opciones, new DialogInterface.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(DialogInterface dialogInterface, int i) {

                if (opciones[i].equals("Elegir de Galeria")){
                    Intent intent=new Intent(Intent.ACTION_PICK,
                            MediaStore.Images.Media.EXTERNAL_CONTENT_URI);
                    intent.setType("image/");  
                    startActivityForResult
                    (intent.createChooser(intent,"Seleccione"),10);
                }else{
                    dialogInterface.dismiss();
                }
            }

        });
        builder.show();
    }
```

here is my logcat report as you show below.

//ERROR.CRASHES IN LINE startActivityForResult()

```
E/AndroidRuntime: FATAL EXCEPTION: main
                  Process: com.example.clemente.prueba6, PID: 4937
                  java.lang.IllegalStateException: Fragment FragmentFotosPerfil{18cbf6df} not attached to Activity
                      at android.support.v4.app.Fragment.startActivityForResult(Fragment.java:1019)
                      at android.support.v4.app.Fragment.startActivityForResult(Fragment.java:1010)
                      at com.example.clemente.prueba6.FragmentFotosPerfil$1.onClick(FragmentFotosPerfil.java:159)
                      at android.support.v7.app.AlertController$AlertParams$3.onItemClick(AlertController.java:1067)
                      at android.widget.AdapterView.performItemClick(AdapterView.java:300)
                      at android.widget.AbsListView.performItemClick(AbsListView.java:1143)
                      at android.widget.AbsListView$PerformClick.run(AbsListView.java:3044)
                      at android.widget.AbsListView$3.run(AbsListView.java:3833)
                      at android.os.Handler.handleCallback(Handler.java:739)
                      at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:95)
                      at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:135)
                      at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:5221)
                      at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Native Method)
                      at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:372)
                      at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:899)
                      at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:694)
```

**Does anyone know the solution to this problem?**

**Thanks in advance**

Comment: it would be much better to handle the result from the activity, so it will be better to run `if(getActivity()!=null) getActivity().startActivityForResult(intent.createChooser(intent,"Seleccione"),10);`

Comment: thank you gmetax, if I use getActivity().startForResult... it returns null

Comment: how where do you call `cargarFotoPerfil2(View view)`? Post full code.

Comment: your issue is that your fragment isn't attached, you have to use your isAdded also

Answer (score 0):

I believe that any way you want to dismiss the Dialog, And it might fix your crash...

Try changing the `onClick` to look like this:

```
@Override
public void onClick(DialogInterface dialogInterface, int i) {

  dialogInterface.dismiss();

  if (opciones[i].equals("Elegir de Galeria")){
    Intent intent = new Intent(Intent.ACTION_PICK, MediaStore.Images.Media.EXTERNAL_CONTENT_URI);
    intent.setType("image/");
    startActivityForResult(intent.createChooser(intent,"Seleccione"),10);
  }
}
```

Comment: thank you HedeH, but the problem is when it runs startActivityforResult. The dialog runs, but when I choose "Elegir Galeria" it crashes

Answer (score 0):

The exception says that you are not attached the fragment or else that attached fragment may be destroyed kindly reattach the fragment.

Answer (score 0):

Use isAdded to check if fragment is attached to Activity.

```
if(isAdded){

    final CharSequence[] opciones={"Elegir de Galeria","Cancelar"};
    final AlertDialog.Builder builder=new AlertDialog.Builder(view.getContext());
    builder.setTitle("Elige una Opción");
    builder.setItems(opciones, new DialogInterface.OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(DialogInterface dialogInterface, int i) {

            if (opciones[i].equals("Elegir de Galeria")){
                Intent intent=new Intent(Intent.ACTION_PICK,
                    MediaStore.Images.Media.EXTERNAL_CONTENT_URI);
                intent.setType("image/");
            startActivityForResult(intent.createChooser(intent,"Seleccione"),10);
            }else{
                dialogInterface.dismiss();
            }
        }

    });

}
```

Comment: it returns false, so is not added, how can I do to fix it?

Comment: Post `FragmentFotosPerfil.java` so that we can help you.

Answer (score 0):

I think you need check your code. Because I replied the fragment and your code is working fine. Maybe your mistake is the way that you are using to load the fragment in the Activity.

I let you the code that i use to launch the fragment. This code is working.

Calling another fragment from **TestFragment**

```
     public class TestFragment extends Fragment {

    public TestFragment() {
        // Required empty public constructor
    }

    @Override
    public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    }

    @Override
    public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container,
                             Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        // Inflate the layout for this fragment
         View v = inflater.inflate(R.layout.fragment_test_two, container, false);

        TestFragmentTwo fragment = new TestFragmentTwo();
        FragmentManager fragmentManager = getActivity().getSupportFragmentManager();

        FragmentTransaction fragmentTransaction = fragmentManager.beginTransaction();
        fragmentTransaction.replace(R.id.container, fragment);
        fragmentTransaction.addToBackStack(fragment.toString());
        fragmentTransaction.setTransition(FragmentTransaction.TRANSIT_FRAGMENT_OPEN);
        fragmentTransaction.commit();

         return v;
    }
}
```

**TestFragmentTwo**

```
public class TestFragmentTwo extends Fragment {

    public TestFragmentTwo() {
        // Required empty public constructor
    }

    @Override
    public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    }

    @Override
    public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container,
                             Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        // Inflate the layout for this fragment
         View v = inflater.inflate(R.layout.fragment_test_two, container, false);


        final CharSequence[] opciones={"Elegir de Galeria","Cancelar"};
        final AlertDialog.Builder builder=new AlertDialog.Builder(v.getContext());
        builder.setTitle("Elige una Opción");
        builder.setItems(opciones, (dialogInterface, i) -> {

            if (opciones[i].equals("Elegir de Galeria")){
                Intent intent=new Intent(Intent.ACTION_PICK,
                        MediaStore.Images.Media.EXTERNAL_CONTENT_URI);
                intent.setType("image/");
                getActivity().startActivityForResult(intent.createChooser(intent,"Seleccione"),10);
            }else{
                dialogInterface.dismiss();
            }
        });
        builder.show();

         return v;
    }
}
```

As you can see, I am loading a fragment from another fragment, and then I am calling the startActivityResult without problem.

I hope it helps you.

Comment: I do the transaction in otrer fragment, not in an actitivy. Could be that the problem?Thank in advance

Comment: do you mean that you launch the fragment from another fragment? I will test it anyway haha